# Outside placement error

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

It compiles but says I have an index out of bounds error which I don't know how to solve.

**Error Message:**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Any help is appreciated and thank you. Here is a section of my code:

```
        ArrayList<listy> list = new ArrayList<listy>();
        ArrayList<listy> list2 = new ArrayList<listy>();

        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {

            for (int f = 0; f < list.size(); f++) {


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //get listy         }
```

Comment: You should show the exact error message with stacktrace.

Comment: @SantiBailors Ok I added that to the original

Comment: How long is your `list` when you do this: `for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
  System.out.println(list.get(i).getRow()` ?

Comment: @jlordo It just gets the row and column of where the ship is placed.

Comment: You declared list and list2 as empty arraylists and before populating either you called .get on them, so index out of bounds 0, 0

Comment: @alfnks in this line of code `System.out.println(list.get(i).getRow()` there is `i` is `0` which would get the first element in the list, but there is no element in the list and thats why you get the error.

Comment: @jlordo How would I edit it to fix it?

Comment: Many ways possible. Either `for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {` instead of `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {` or first `add()` some elements to the list before `get()`ting them...

Comment: @jlordo Ok I used for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { and it ran but it is only showing 1 red dot.

Comment: Happy debugging ;-) Step through your code, analyze the value of your variables and he lengths of your lists. You'll find it. Using g the debugger in your IDE will help and teach you alot.

Comment: @jlordo Thanks for your previous help but I looked through my code and am not sure why only one dot is showing each time still

Comment: Your code having variable as list, list2, f, i, c, is very hard to read for me. Either add more print statements to debug or step through your code with a debugger to find the issue (self explanatory variable names help make the code more understable)

Comment: Why did you delete the code? It is become unclear now, did my answer solve your problem? If you have other questions I suggest to create a new question, good luck

Comment: My code compiles and runs but it only gives one dot and I don't know why

Comment: @Zich didn't mention your name so look above here

Comment: @alfnks That would be another problem, your first problem was an index out of bound error, and the code was not running fine(the StackTrace you have attached), the answer I have posted address's the first issue, I kindly suggest to create a new question and ask why does your logic not working. Good luck

Comment: @Zich Yea thanks I managed to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You are running the main method from a class called BattleBoats not the main method from Battleship. The error is resulting from you calling the get() method of the ArrayList Class without it being populated as the size of the list is 0 in the stack trace. Please provide code for BattleBoats

Comment: @SantiBailors Yea I am aware but just changed the name cause of the edit

Comment: Stacktrace shows the get() message is sent to Arraylist with zero size in main(), I believe the problem is in the  for loop (hard code controlled loop)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialized  *list*
But you used it in your *for* *loop* to write its values!

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getRow() + " " + list.get(i).getCol());
```

Change it to this :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getRow() + " " + list.get(i).getCol());
```

Your Stacktrace points to a get() message that is sent to an empty ArrayList in main() method (above loop).

Comment: @alfnks Yes I noticed after a post it and correct it, thanks for your comment :)